# License for lightning/Force.com

Tags: lightning, force.com, lightning-apps, force.com-sites, lightning-community

I have a question on lightning.

1. If I have a lightning App, should i need License?
2. In Sales force, Assume that I create a web page which is public and million users are viewing my page or using my page, now that it is 25$ per user, should i need 25 million licenses?

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce have an offering called [Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites) where cost is based on usage rather than the number of unique visitors. This is not designed for authenticated access but rather for providing publicly accessible material. (I'm assuming Lightning is supported for Sites but don't know that.)

To add authentication (login) where the identify of each user is known, a [Customer Portal](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_customer_portal_implementation_guide.pdf) capability is available. Here there is a cost per user per month. It is considerably lower than a conventional license cost, but is certainly not insignificant. You would need to talk to your Salesforce account manager to explore that pricing.

Comment: Lightning Out works in a Sites Visualforce page, but you're not in the `one.app` container.